# withFormik, pass function as props

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I am using Formik to build an user input Form. And I am using withFormik to handle my Form.
I am currently passing my handleSubmit inside my  component like this:

```
export const CreateForm = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({
    primarySkill: "12"
  }),
  validationSchema: () => FormSchema,

  handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)); // For testing
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 1000);
  }
})(MyForm);
```

Instead of doing this way, I would like to pass something like this `<CreateForm handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />` in my App.js (root) component. Can anyone give me a hint how to do it, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a function via props in the way that you hint at at the bottom of your question. Then you can wrap the `withFormik` call inside the function body of your `CreateForm` component so that you can pass props to the `CreateForm` component and have `CreateForm` control how those props get mapped to the Formik component.

For example:

```js
const MyComponent = props => {
    function handleSubmit(values, { setSubmitting }) {
        // handle
    }

    return (
        <CreateForm handleSubmit={ handleSubmit }/>
    )
}

const CreateForm = props => {
    const { handleSubmit } = props;

    const MyFormWithFormik = withFormik({
        // ...,
        handleSubmit: handleSubmit,
    })(MyForm);

    return <MyFormWithFormik/>
}
```

Comment: So, in my app.js I render the <My Component /> ? Sorry, I am very confused with withFomik() function

Comment: It renders an empty result for me
```
export const CreatePDSA = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
  return withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues: () => ({
      PDSAName: '',
      PDSAtype: '',
      primarySkill: '',
      secondarySkill: '',
      minPrice: '',
      currency: '',
      format: ''
    }),
    validationSchema: () => CreatePdsaSchema,

    handleSubmit: handleSubmit
  })(CreatePDSAForm);
};
```

Comment: @CCL I see what the problem was. The `withFormik` call returns a component (not a renderable instance), so returning the output of `withFormik` was actually a mistake on my part, sorry about that! Really you want to return an instance of the wrapped `withFormik` form. See the update to the answer for details.

Comment: This is applying a HOC dynamically. With the above you'll lose all form state on remount (formik fields will revert to initialValues). Either rewrite as a classic class component and apply the HOC in the constructor or apply the HOC outside a component definition. Read: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#dont-use-hocs-inside-the-render-method

Answer (score 1):

The second argument in the handleSubmit argument set is the formik bag. The props are passed into the formik bag. The props passed into the formik bag can be accessed like so:
`handleSubmit: (values, { props }) => {...your function here}`